# use websvn address in repository url

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, websvn

i installed subversion and svn in my debian in the server

when i see my websvn address in my browser `"http://10.19.20.203/websvn"` i can see the web svn page

but when my windows client set this address (`"http://10.19.20.203/websvn"`) in the tortoiseSVN repository url . this error will be occured

```
Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://10.19.20.203/websvn'
```

what's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must to use **URL of real repository** in TortoiseSVN
2. Root of WebSVN folder is not browsable by RepoBrowser anyway (it isn't repository)
3. All repositories URLs can be found in configuration file of WebSVN (and, in common, URL of repo in WebSVN does not correlate with real URL - inside single installation both local and remote repositories can be used)